# $(-1)^0$ , calculating zeroth power of a negative number

Tags: exponential-function

I wish to calculate the zeroth power of a negative number

$(-1)^0 = (-1)^{2-2}$
=$\frac{(-1)^2}{(-1)^2} = 1$

But when I put it in a calculator, it comes out to be $-1$.

Comment: How exactly are you entering the calculation? In normal entry, it should be $1, \pm, x^y, 0, =$. If you hit the minus sign as the first key you will likely get the wrong result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wrote $-1^0$, so the calculator interpreted it as $-(1^0)$ and not as $(-1)^0$. Use parentheses.